# Indexing columns included in a joint primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Given a DB with a primary index on the columns foo and bar, is it worthwhile adding an individual index on the single column foo (assuming that most queries are ... WHERE foo = '...')?  If it makes a difference, I'm on pgsql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If index is `(foo,bar)` - in this order, you don't need another index on `foo`.
Otherwise you do.